# Is the space $\mathcal{H}=\{v\in H^1(\Omega):\Delta v\in H^1(\Omega)^*\}$ a Banach space?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a Lipschitz domain in $\Bbb R^n$, is the space
$$\mathcal{H}=\{v\in H^1(\Omega):\Delta v\in H^1(\Omega)^*\}$$
a Hilbert space when endowed with the norm $\|\cdot\|_\mathcal{H} = \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}+\|\Delta u\|_{H^1(\Omega)^*}$?
To be a Banach space it just needs to be a closed subspace of $H^1(\Omega)$. Clearly the space is closed under addition, and if $u_k$ is cauchy in $\mathcal{H}$ then $\Delta u_k$ is cauchy in $H^1(\Omega)^*$ which is a Banach space, and so there is a $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ and a $w\in H^1(\Omega)^*$ such that
$$u_k\to u\quad\mbox{in}\quad H^1(\Omega),$$
$$\Delta u_k\to w\quad\mbox{in}\quad H^1(\Omega)^*,$$
is this enough to deduce that $w=\Delta u$?

We can see that for $v\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$

$\begin{align}\langle\Delta u|v\rangle&=\int_\Omega u\Delta v\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_\Omega u_k\Delta v\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle\Delta u_k|v\rangle\\
&=\langle w|v\rangle\end{align}$

which I believe implies that $w=\Delta u$ in the $H^1(\Omega)^*$ sense by the definition of the weak derivative.

Comment: I don't get why $u_k$ and $\Delta u_k$ are only converging weakly.  (btw, there are two typos: mathcal{B} should be H and immediately after there is a missing k.)

Comment: @Giovanni, thanks I have changed these things.

Comment: What exactly does "$\Delta  u\in H^1(\Omega)$" mean? That is, how is the action of $\Delta u$ on $H^1(\Omega)$ defined?

Comment: @NormalHuman, by the divergence theorem i.e., $\langle\Delta u|v\rangle =\langle\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}|v\rangle-\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla v$

Comment: Okay, but this involves integrating $\partial u/\partial n$ over the boundary. How is that defined?

Comment: It is defined by the duality pairing $\langle\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}|v\rangle=+\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+\langle\Delta u|v\rangle$

Comment: @NormalHuman I'm going from these notes: http://www.ltcc.ac.uk/courses/Applied%20Computational%20Methods/ACM2007Chap4.pdf

Comment: I took a look on your notes, but I can not understand the definition of $\Delta u$ as a functional over $H^1$. I think that if $\nabla v\in H(div;\Omega)$ then the operator from $\{v\in H^1(\Omega): \nabla v\in H(div;\Omega)\}$ to $H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ is well defined - just see the construction of the normal trace  operator $\gamma_n: H(div;\Omega)\rightarrow H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)$.

Comment: @ellya: This looks like a circular definition: you define $\Delta u$ via $\partial u/\partial n$ and vice versa.